# How to express a situation in which a series of events take place 1-week after each other

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

In a course that I need to describe, there are 4 exams with the following schedule:

> 1/1/2012 Exam 1
>
> 1/8/2012 Exam 2
>
> 1/15/2012 Exam 3
>
> 1/22/2012 Exam 4

To express this, I used

> There was a one-week span between each assignment.

However, I am not sure if this sentence expresses the situation well? Any suggestions?

Comment: Native speakers would be more likely to use ***gap*** rather than ***span*** in such a context, but that's as much a matter of semantics and intended emphasis as "vocabulary choice".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be safe saying "four exams are scheduled for this month, with **a seven-day interval** between each one of them."

Comment: Or "... every Friday, starting on the first."